# Using GCC's function instrumentation, why does using C++ STL containers or stream I/O cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, instrumentation

I recently read about using GCC's code generation features (specifically, the [-finstrument-functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) compiler flag) to easily add instrumentation to my programs. I thought it sounded really cool and went to try it out on a previous C++ project. After several revisions of my patch, I found that any time I tried to use an STL container or print to stdout using C++ stream I/O, my program would immediately crash with a segfault. My first idea was to maintain a `std::list` of `Event` structs

```
typedef struct  
{
    unsigned char event_code;
    intptr_t func_addr;
    intptr_t caller_addr;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    timespec ts;
}Event;

list<Event> events;
```

which would be written to a file when the program terminated. GDB told me that when I tried to add an `Event` to the list, calling `events.push_back(ev)` itself initiated an instrumentation call. This wasn't terrible surprising and made sense after I thought about it for a bit, so on to plan 2.

The example in the [blog](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/) which got me involved in all this mess didn't do anything crazy, it simply wrote a string to a file using `fprintf()`. I didn't think there would be any harm in using C++'s stream-based I/O instead of the older `(f)printf()`, but that assumption proved to be wrong. This time, instead of a nearly-infinite death spiral, GDB reported a fairly normal-looking descent into the standard library... followed by a segfault.

## A Short Example

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" __attribute__ ((no_instrument_function)) void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void*, void*);

list<string> text;

extern "C" void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void* /* unused */, void* /* unused */)
{
    // Method 1
    text.push_back("NOPE");

    // Method 2
    cout << "This explodes" << endl;

    // Method 3
    printf("This works!");
}
```

## Sample GDB Backtrace

### Method 1

```
#0  _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff7380720, bytes=29) at malloc.c:3570
#1  0x00007ffff704ca45 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=29) at malloc.c:2924
#2  0x00007ffff7652ded in operator new(unsigned long) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff763ba89 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff763d495 in char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff763d5e3 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) () from  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00000000004028c1 in __cyg_profile_func_enter () at src/instrumentation.cpp:82
#7  0x0000000000402c6f in std::move<std::string&> (__t=...) at     /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/move.h:82
#8  0x0000000000402af5 in std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>   >::push_back(std::string&&) (this=0x6055c0, __x=...) at   /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:993
#9  0x00000000004028d2 in __cyg_profile_func_enter () at src/instrumentation.cpp:82
#10 0x0000000000402c6f in std::move<std::string&> (__t=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/move.h:82
#11 0x0000000000402af5 in std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::push_back(std::string&&) (this=0x6055c0, __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:993
#12 0x00000000004028d2 in __cyg_profile_func_enter () at src/instrumentation.cpp:82
#13 0x0000000000402c6f in std::move<std::string&> (__t=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/move.h:82
#14 0x0000000000402af5 in std::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::push_back(std::string&
...
```

### Method 2

```
#0  0x00007ffff76307d1 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&) ()
    from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7630ee9 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&  std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff76312ef in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x000000000040251e in __cyg_profile_func_enter () at src/instrumentation.cpp:81
#4  0x000000000040216d in _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN8GLWindow7attribsE () at src/glwindow.cpp:164
#5  0x0000000000402f2d in __libc_csu_init ()
#6  0x00007ffff6feb700 in __libc_start_main (main=0x402cac <main()>, argc=1, ubp_av=0x7fffffffe268, 
init=0x402ed0 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
stack_end=0x7fffffffe258) at libc-start.c:185
#7  0x0000000000401589 in _start ()
```

## Environment:

- Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (x64)
- GCC 4.6.3
- Intel 3750K CPU
- 8GB RAM

Comment: My guess is that the stl functions are probably inlined and are subject to the same instrumentation, causing an infinite recursion.  I would suggest trying having your profiling functions in a separate source file that is not compiled with the instrumenting option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with using `cout` in the instrumentation function is that the instrumentation function is being called by `__libc_csu_init()` which is a very early part of the runtime's initialization - before global C++ objects get a chance to be constructed (in fact, I think `__libc_csu_init()` is responsible for kicking off those constructors - at least indirectly).

So `cout` hasn't had a chance to be constructed yet and trying to use it doesn't work very well...

And that may well be the problem you run into with trying to use `std::List` after fixing the infinite recursion ([mentioned in Dave S' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233482/12711)).

If you're willing to lose some instrumentation during initialization, you can do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int initialization_complete = 0;

using namespace std;

extern "C" __attribute__ ((no_instrument_function)) void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void*, void*);

extern "C" void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void* /* unused */, void* /* unused */)
{
    if (!initialization_complete) return;

    // Method 2
    cout << "This explodes" << endl;

    // Method 3
    printf("This works! ");
}

void foo()
{
    cout << "foo()" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    initialization_complete = 1;
    foo();
}
```

Comment: interesting... so basically if I want to proceed down this path I need to stick to straight C? I don't suppose there's a way to tell when the C++ global objects are done being constructed? My thought is to possibly "ignore" calls to the instrumentation function before the environment is ready.

Comment: @rjacks - I imagine there's a way to tell when the constructors have completed, but using it would probably require some in-depth knowledge (that I don't have) of the initialization mechanisms gcc/g++ use.  There's probably a good way to prevent `__libc_csu_init()` from calling the instrumentation function, but I don't know how off the top of my head.

Comment: I just read your updated answer, looks like you and I were having the same thought, but your way is much simpler :-)

Answer (score 2):

The first case seems to be an infinite loop, resulting in stack overflow.  This is probably because std::list is a template, and it's code is generated as part of the translation unit where you're using it.  This causes it to get instrumented as well.  So you call push_back, which calls the handler, which calls push_back, ...

The second, if I had to guess, might be similar, though it's harder to tell.

The solution is to compile the instrumentation functions separately, without the -finstrument-functions.  Note, the example blog compiled the trace.c separately, without the option.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned before that I had excluded the instrumentation source file using GCC's -finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list flag. Nevertheless, I tried your suggestion to compile the instrumentation code separately and without the flag, with little effect. There is no longer an infinite loop when trying to use the std::list, which is good, but it still generates a segmentation fault in libstdc++.so.6. If you like I can post the commands I use to compile the program, and an updated backtrace. I'm not sure it would help, though.